# check if script is running 10 times, if not restart

Tags: bash, awk

Hey, i have some problems with bash..

want to check if the *ROBSTER* process is running *RUNNING* times if not start until;

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='ROBSTER'
RUNNING=20

var=$(ps aux | grep $SERVICE|grep -v SCREEN|wc -l)
echo $var

if [ $var -gt $RUNNING ]
then
for  i in $(seq $var RUNNING)
do
echo "start" 
done
fi
```

but it wont work :-/
:D hope you could help me

Comment: use `#!/bin/sh -x` for debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux | grep ROBSTER|grep -v SCREEN
```

after u have changed the question:

```
var=$(ps aux | grep ROBSTER|grep -v SCREEN|wc -l)

echo $var 
if [ var -gt 10 ]
then 
    do run your process the number of times you need
fi
```

Comment: oki, but how to start die difference of the running processes... ? :-/

Comment: I feel its a homework.if yes please tag it as homework.regarding the difference.you can do some calculation inside the script subtracting the var from 10 and then decide how many times the process can be run.